# how to restrict /wp/wp-admin files to my private ip adresses

Tags: nginx

I have a wordpress site under /wp directory, with nginx web server.I want to restrict  /wp/wp-admin files to my private ip adresses and return an error to unathorised clients.
the problem is wp-admin folder can be easily restricted but files are still reachable!

```
server {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location /main {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?q=$uri;
}

    error_page   500 502 503 504 404 403 400 /error.html;
    location = /error.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a question about iptables, you should use more accurate tags like nginx.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is with a `location` stanza in your config file, such as:

```
location /wp/wp-admin/ {
  allow 192.168.1.0/24;
  deny all;
}
```

Your question made it sound as though you had tried this already without success though?  Can you post your exact configuration for this directory?

Comment: above configuration will restrict access on /wp/wp-admin, but php scripts can be executed under this directory. e.g. /wp/wp-admin/script.php
i want to restrict access to everything under this directory including php script, images, js ,...

Comment: There is a difference between `location = /wp/wp-admin/` and `location /wp/wp-admin/`.  The first will only be for *exactly* a request of `/wp/wp-admin/`, while the latter will match anything starting with `/wp/wp-admin/`.

Comment: If I place it below my fast-cgi parameters nothing happens but if I place it above my fast-cgi parameters, it denys well but allowed ip addresses wil see the php sources

Comment: Please post your configuration in your original question, all I can do now is guess.

Comment: I've added my configuration file to above post.please check it

Comment: I'm confused, I don't see where you're every trying to restrict wp-admin.  Did you paste the whole configuration?

Comment: This solution will cause PHP issue, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

`wp-admin` still needs to pass PHP

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php)(/.*) {       
        error_page 403;

        deny all;
        allow 1.2.4.5;

        add_header X-Admin "admin";
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        // 1st way, create create a common fastcgi_pass
        include conf-settings/php-live.conf; // most important


       // 2nd way, add fast_cgi directly
       fastcgi_pass thg_upstream_php;
}
```